# Firemonkey multi device project Continuous Integration

Tags: android, ios, jenkins, build, firemonkey

Is there a way to build a Firemonkey multi device project for any of the other platform other than windows?

I've already succesfully build a project that was set on Win32 using Rad Studio plugin that uses MSBuild, but it would also be nice if I can build it for iOS and Android as well.

When I set the platform to Android for example it fails, because it tries to build a windows application. It should use Android SDK instead of MSBuild.

Comment: What prevents you from doing it? In the Project manager you can choose what Target Platform to build for. Simply choose iOS or Android. Please be more specific about what your problem is, or else it is likely to be downvoted.

Comment: @Hans i've updated my question. Hope this is enough info.

Comment: Do you mean you want to make builds automatically without the IDE?

Comment: @SergeyKrasilnikov yes, that's one of the main perposes of jenkins.

Comment: Well, if no one will outrun me, I'll add full answer few days later, after I finish my current task. It's almost similar to this question. In brief, you can build binaries via msbuild, then (following IDE way) put all deployed files in special path and make *.apk via paclient, and finally install that via adb. Paclient commands can be seen in Messages of the IDE.

Comment: @SergeyKrasilnikov that would be great!

Comment: @SergeyKrasilnikov still waiting for your answer

Comment: @Remi Sorry, I'm to busy right now. May be next week.. I hope a brief scheme can help you before I come back to that task.